# whether an .py file which is interacting with cmd can be converted to .exe file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, cmd

I wrote a python script which interacts with cmd shell and fetches some data through os.popen("command here").read() .Now can i change that script to exe file 
whether it is possible such a type of script which are interacting with cmd 
to executable .

Comment: If you mean it's a console application that either inherits a console from its parent or allocates a new one, then, yes, programs that freeze a script, such as py2exe and PyInstaller, can create a console application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FrontPage). It does exactly what you ask for.

Comment: and can u please tell me whether cmd interactive scripts can be made executable

Comment: Yes, the link I provided is a method by which you can create a completely standalone executable file from a python script. You will be able to run this in cmd.exe from the directory it is stored in. If you want to be able to run the script.exe produced system-wide without being in the folder it is stored in, you must either place the script.exe in a directory already included in your Windows path variable, or add the directory you want to store script.exe in to your Windows path variable.

Comment: Thanks evan i will try

Comment: The easiest way to get this working system-wide is to place the script.exe produced by py2exe in C:\Windows\System32. Good luck!

Comment: import py2exe 
ImportError: No module named py2exe 
I installed it but i am getting above  error while executing :( any path should be set. ?

Comment: Are you using the correct python version when you try to import it? When starting idle, the version listed at the top (2.7, etc) should match the py2exe installer you downloaded from sourceforge. ex: py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.7.exe